# Ruby / Rails - File naming conventions and dealing with uppercase model names (i.e. CSV vs Csv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm using a model to track CSV uploads. When using FactoryGirl in my specs, OR when trying to access the model via an association (i.e. `user.csv_uploads`) I get the following error when trying to use the linter.

```
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

LoadError:
  Unable to autoload constant CsvUpload, expected .../APP_NAME/app/models/csv_upload.rb to define it


user.csv_uploads

LoadError: Unable to autoload constant CsvUpload, expected .../APP_NAME/app/models/csv_upload.rb to define it
```

That file does define a model called `CSVUpload`, but strictly following naming conventions, I guess it should be `CsvUpload`. Currently the model loads correctly, and typing something like `CSVUpload.new` in the console works as expected. But certain other situations have the load error. I assume this is when trying to convert a symbol or filename into a class name, and then trying to use that. i.e. `:csv_upload.to_s.camelize.constantize`. Is there a simple way to fix this? Or will a be a constant uphill battle that is best fixed by going with `CsvUpload`?

Comment: @SimpleLime Yes! This works. If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails uses the [`ActiveSupport::Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) for things like constantize-ing strings, so you can tell the inflector that **csv** should be an [`acronym`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym) and not a part of the usual "first character uppercase and the rest lowercase" that is used for most things. You do this in an initializer (looks to be there by default **config/initializers/inflections.rb**) by using the following code:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.acronym 'CSV'
end
```